# Why is the while loop here printing in the same line?

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop, printing

The following illustrates an example while loop in Python:

```
count = 0
print('Starting')
while count < 10:
   print(count, ' ', end='') # part of the while loop
   count += 1 # also part of the while loop
print() # not part of the while loop
print('Done')
```

The result of running this example is:

```
Starting
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
Done
```

I don't understand why the while loop prints in the same line if the code if the code is loop again and print() is run afresh in the second loop. I was expecting the number to be printed in different lines. What did I mess up in my understanding of while loops?

Comment: I am learning Python from a book, I haven't reached that far yet, This was an example given to explain while loops which got me confused about the print function. But Bill the Lizard was a very big help. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the `end` parameter to Python's `print` function is a newline character. That's why printing in a loop normally prints values on separate lines. (It would be tedious to append your own newline character to every message you print, so the default makes sense in most cases.)

By passing `end=''` you're overriding the default so that each value is printed on the same line.

See the [`print` function documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print).